# On clicking row of present table appearance of another table

Tags: javascript, html

I have 2 tables:
1.) escalation table (FK- source_id
2.) source table (PK- source_id)
I am printing escalation table first.
Eg: Escalation table output:
SourceID   Status  Notice
1          open    name1
2          close   name2
3          open    name3

on clicking anywhere in row1 of escalation table,I need to fetch the source_id and print data of source table . And hence same thing with row2,row3 and so on..

My present code is enclosed within this post: here I am printing escalation table, But on clicking row I am printing same data again.How can I print the data of source table on clicking the row? Please help.

```js
(function () {
    if (window.addEventListener) {
        window.addEventListener('load', run, false);
    } else if (window.attachEvent) {
        window.attachEvent('onload', run);
    }

    function run() {
        var t = document.getElementById('myTable');
        t.onclick = function (event) {
            event = event || window.event; //IE8
            var target = event.target || event.srcElement;
            while (target && target.nodeName != 'TR') { // find TR
                target = target.parentElement;
            }
            //if (!target) { return; } //tr should be always found
            var cells = target.cells; //cell collection - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableRowElement
            //var cells = target.getElementsByTagName('td'); //alternative
            if (!cells.length || target.parentNode.nodeName == 'THEAD') {
                return;
            }
            var f1 = document.getElementById('sourceID');
            var f2 = document.getElementById('status');
            var f3 = document.getElementById('notice');            
            f1.value = cells[0].innerHTML;
            f2.value = cells[1].innerHTML;
            f3.value = cells[2].innerHTML;
            
            //console.log(target.nodeName, event);
        };
    }

})();
```

```html
<table border="1" id="myTable" cellspacing="1">
    
        <tr>
            <th>sourceID</th>
            <th>Status</th>
            <th>Notice</th>
        </tr>
    <tr>
<tr>
 <td>1</td>
 <td>open</td>
 <td>name1</td>
 </tr>
 
 <tr>
 <td>2</td>
 <td>close</td>
 <td>name2</td>
 </tr>
 
 <tr>
 <td>3</td>
 <td>open</td>
 <td>name3</td>
 </tr>
 
</table>
<table border="1">
<tr>
<th>sourceID</th>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Notice</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>sourceID is:
<input type="text" id="sourceID" />
</td>
<td>status is:
<input type="text" id="status" />
</td>
<td>notice is:
<input type="text" id="notice" />
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
```

Comment: You are not using PHP, that's the problem.

Comment: sorry I dint get u @Justinas